# Listing Tags Of A certain post in a certain category of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, tags

here is the issue , I have a wordpress website, which has some categories let say NY & NV & CA. 
there are posts in each category which may have the same Title. but they have different Tags ob every single posts .

now I want to query post's tags in another page , to show only the very certain post I want to get.

here is the code I am using :

```
 <?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'Name' => 'Las Vegas',
    'category_name' => 'NY', 'NV', 'CA');

$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : ?>
<?php 

$posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
    if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name . '<br/>';
      }
    }
 ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but the problem is when I run the query is list all the tags in all Categories or it stop listing as soon as it find 'las vegas' which could be a wrong 'las vegas' in another category. I even tries to add only NV as category query but still list the same result.

Comment: can have category_name more values? If so, then put it also in an array. Example: `'category_name' => array('NY', 'NV', 'CA')`

Comment: No, this is not working , I tried and whole page failed to load.

Comment: but I solved it and I will post the answer for every one to see. thans any way.

Comment: `<?php
$args = array(
 'post__in' => array(548),
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'category__in' => array(3897),);
 
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : ?>
<?php 

$posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
 if ($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
     echo "<a href='";
  the_permalink();
  echo $tag->name . "'>" . $tag->name . "</a> <br/> ";
   }
 }
 ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
`